# Why is it "desperate want make them" instead of "desperate want makes them"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs

This context comes from the book "Black Rednecks And White Liberals" by Thomas Sowell.

"He urged charitable efforts toward blacks after they were freed, lest “desperate want” **make** them dangerous to those around them. But he too saw the freeing of millions of people unprepared for freedom as creating a serious danger to the society as a whole."

I know that "**want**" is an uncountable noun that means:

a lack of something:

*For want of anything better to do I watched television for a while.*(Cambridge dictionary)

I know that there is a rule that applies to **collective nouns** that they take a plural verb when each of the individuals in the group is considered as a separate entity e.g:

1. The team **is** painting a mural. (The team collectively paints the mural, so the verb is singular.)
2. The team **are** in disagreement about how to paint the mural. (The people on the team disagree with one another, so the verb is plural.)

Does this rule **also apply also to uncountable nouns** as the one in the book? If not, why the verb takes the plural form in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nothing to do with the number.

*Lest* is one of those words which takes the base form of the verb rather than the normal inflected form.

This tends to be a rather formal or old-fashioned use; but "lest" is rarely used in ordinary speech anyway.

*Though* can also take the base form, but this is even more old-fashioned.

Some verbs also take this form, notably *demand*.

(Traditionally this form is called the "subjunctive", but since it is identical with the base form of the verb for every verb in the language - even "be" -  I think it is a needless complication to give it a special name)

Comment: lest is a verb? I thought it was a conjunction, meaning for fear that.

Comment: Lest is indeed a conjunction. I didn't say it was a verb: I said that (like the verb _demand_) it takes the base form of the verb. I'll reword.